# RSA sign by USB-token+C# and verify by Java

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, rsa, signature

Im trying to verify RSA signature on server side that was signed on client by USB-token and .Net.

So, i have:

**Public key**:
**Modulus**:

```
zpF/kA34TKgsx1G2arEwceaKf1gzEsV3gHPtzmABimmrb2hlVDmcix2Pt554U+LHD/okgnNesSwww8FGCaQBmw==
```

**Exponent**:

```
AQAB
```

**Source data**:

```
29062015
```

**Signature base64**:

```
77+9zqYT77+9d8WL77+977+92JXvv73Zqe+/vVfvv73vv73vv71SYB9b77+9BXob77+9DO+/veqGn++/ve+/vVXSqtWdRixlSyDvv70iVe+/vQ8x77+977+977+977+9bFF+77+9Nw==
```

My Java code to verify:

```
public static void test() {
    String modB64 = "zpF/kA34TKgsx1G2arEwceaKf1gzEsV3gHPtzmABimmrb2hlVDmcix2Pt554U+LHD/okgnNesSwww8FGCaQBmw==";
    String expB64 = "AQAB";

    String phrase = "29062015";
    String sign = "77+9zqYT77+9d8WL77+977+92JXvv73Zqe+/vVfvv73vv73vv71SYB9b77+9BXob77+9DO+/veqGn++/ve+/vVXSqtWdRixlSyDvv70iVe+/vQ8x77+977+977+977+9bFF+77+9Nw==";

    PublicKey pubKey = constructPublicKey(modB64, expB64);
    Log.m("ver: " + verify(pubKey, phrase.getBytes("UTF-8"), b64decode(sign)));
}


private static PublicKey constructPublicKey(String modB64, String expB64) 
                throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    BigInteger mod = new BigInteger(b64decode(modB64));
    BigInteger exp = new BigInteger(b64decode(expB64));
    RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(mod, exp);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    PublicKey key = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    return key;
}

private static boolean verify(
        PublicKey publicKey, byte[] message, byte[] signature)
        throws SignatureException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException,
        NoSuchProviderException {
    Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC");
    sign.initVerify(publicKey);
    sign.update(message);
    return sign.verify(signature);
}

private static final byte[] b64decode(String data)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

But it always returns false.
Also i tried to use another encoding (ASCII, windows-1251) with *getBytes()* method and this does not solve problem.
Also i tried to verify without BouncyCatle.

But signature and key pair must be correct, i guess, because i tested it by C# and this working fine:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAParameters prsa = new RSAParameters();
prsa.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String("zpF/kA34TKgsx1G2arEwceaKf1gzEsV3gHPtzmABimmrb2hlVDmcix2Pt554U+LHD/okgnNesSwww8FGCaQBmw==");
prsa.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String("AQAB");
rsa.ImportParameters(prsa);

string data = "29062015";
string sign64 = "77+9zqYT77+9d8WL77+977+92JXvv73Zqe+/vVfvv73vv73vv71SYB9b77+9BXob77+9DO+/veqGn++/ve+/vVXSqtWdRixlSyDvv70iVe+/vQ8x77+977+977+977+9bFF+77+9Nw==";

byte[] dtBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data);
byte[] sgBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(sign64);

if (rsa.VerifyData(dtBuffer, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), sgBuffer))
   result.Text += "\nRight!";
```

Help me, please.
Whats wrong on Java side? Why i can verify this signature by C#, but can't by Java?

Comment: You have the standard BigInteger bug, for RSA you have to use the constructor `BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude)` with `signnum=1` otherwise you can get negative values.

Comment: Yes, i know about this, and i also tried to pass 1 as first arg to BigInteger constructor, but it also does not solve problem

Comment: `byte[] dtBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data);` ... what's the default encoding? Isn't it UTF-16LE instead of UTF-8? Please verify that the resulting byte array is the same for Java and C#!

Comment: ... and keep with the `signnum=1` indicated by robert, it could be that there are two issues instead of one.